# Network graph visualisation

Tags: c++, graph, graph-visualization

Is there any way to show the output of a program in a graphic format that contains vertices and edges ?

Program input will be a 2d matrix and the output will be a picture containing vertices and edges ?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do it is to use [**graphviz**](http://www.graphviz.org), a toolset for visualizing graphs. The steps would be:

1. Generate a `.dot` file from your graph data. [The DOT language is quite straightforward](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html), you should be able to do it without problems.
2. From the command line, call the appropriate graphviz tool on your `.dot` file (which usually is `dot`), example for SVG output: `dot -Tsvg -ofile.svg file.dot`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [igraph](http://igraph.org/), which is implemented in C (and also available as R and Python packages). Here's an example of the kind of picture you can produce (taken from [this page](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-look-at-the-igraph-package/)):
[image]

Comment: When i run examples given in Igraph documentation,the output of the program does not produce a picture rather it gives output in terminal.Where as I want the output should be a picture.
How to do it?
Provide the steps!!

Comment: My bad, according to this post, igraph can't generate plots when using the C version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022102/no-graph-is-being-displayed-in-igraph. I have only been using the R version, so I was not aware of this limitation. Sorry! You should switch to GraphViz then, as there doesn't seem to be many C libraries for graph visualization. You can also have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751826/which-c-graph-library-should-i-use